# Processing dataframe in chunks

Tags: python, dataframe, chunks

I need to process a large dataframe in chunks and I applied this function:

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for i in chunker(df,chunk_size):
      ....
```

However, when I run this, I get error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Do you have another way to process dataframe in chunks or to adjust above script?

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use iloc for this index sliciing over the rows:

```py
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq.iloc[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

for i in chunker(df,chunk_size):
      ....
```

the reason is `df[]` is for looking up columns and it does not take a slice argument. `df.loc` is for row-index lookups which do not necessarily match incremental indexing (position based). You can read [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=dataframe+loc+vs+iloc) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your quick answer. I tried again following your recommendation, but still I get error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xxx'

if I run the same code for a different dataframe, built using np.random.randn, it works fine.
Also, the error is not given if I do not divide the dataframe in chunks.
Any clue?

Comment: I understand your reply is adressing mine. Can you share more of your code? I fail to see what could not be an integer in your example. Where do you set the value of `chunk_size` for instance?